# Using Azure API Management Service, how do I parse a request property before sending to backend API?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a request that comes from a client app, and I need to conditionally parse 1 of the request fields that is sent.

Ex. 
Assume I POST with a request body with two fields

`{"ID":"123","IPAddress":"127.0.0.1"}`

or

```
{"ID":"123","IPAddress":"127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2"}
```

I need to check if the IP address has a comma separated set, and if so parse the left-most IPAddress

How can I achieve this exactly using Azure API Management Gateway API? Policy?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested but you should be able to use set-body policy for it:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-body>
        @{
            var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>();
            if (body.Property("IPAddress").Contains(","))
            {
                var ips = body.Property("IPAddress").Split(",");

                body.Property("IPAddress").Value = ips[0].Trim();
            }
        }
        </set-body>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

Comment: I think it might need the return statement?

Comment: I did it based on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-on-set-body-policy/